# PHP ODBC SELECT returns incomplete field

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I've migrated a database from MS SQL 2005 (Windows Server 2003) to MS SQL 2012 (windows Server 2012 R2). Everything is working well except one thing.

Whenever I try in PHP with ODBC to get a specific column (unfortunately named "text") and the field has a big content, the result is incomplete. some of the Content's missing, just not existent. If I try the SQL command in SQL Management Studio, the result is correct.

I've tried it with the following two methods (same result):

```
$query = odbc_exec ($dbh, "SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE id = '$page'");
if ($data = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
    extract($data);
    echo $text;
}

//Method 2 is near the same but with the following SQL command and with odbc_result instead of extract();
SET textsize 2147483647 SELECT text FROM artikel WHERE id = '$page'
```

Comment: does the contents contain a html tags or something ?

Comment: If the column data type among large object data types? text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), and xml? /// Side note: I believe the ODBC driver supports prepared statements for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes the contents contains a lot of html tags (table, tr, td) but it's cut in the middle of the code. Even in the middle of a simple word.

Comment: Yes the field is a large object. Originally it was text, but I converted it to varchar(max)

Comment: If it helps, the content in the database is 6190 characters long and cut after 4046.

Comment: @giklo Please have a look at the [odbc.defaultlrl](http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.configuration.php#ini.uodbc.defaultlrl) directive and the [odbc_longreadlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-longreadlen.php) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution (thanks to @Álvaro González)
I added the following two lines to the code (after odbc_exec())

```
odbc_binmode($query, ODBC_BINMODE_PASSTHRU);
odbc_longreadlen($query, 16384); //Set the length of the displayed value to 16384
```

Thanks everyone for help